# How to change the function of a button on secondary form when button on primary form is clicked

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button

I'm making a program where I want a button on form2 to be linked to play a different sound depending on what button I click in form1.

How may this be done?

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/cNH6da92 I changed the names of stuff to make it more straightforward but it's the same general thing. I need to change what the sound button does depending on what I click on the other form

Comment: I suggest you to use `Delegates`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form1.vb

```
Public beepButtonClicked As Boolean = False
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    beepButtonClicked = True
End Sub
```

Form2.vb

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Form1.beepButtonClicked = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("Button clicked after beepButton was clicked")
    End If
End Sub
```

Or if you want multiple sounds:

Form1.vb

```
Public beepButtonClicked As String = "sounds/sound1.wav"
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    beepButtonClicked = "sounds/sound2.wav"
End Sub
```

Form2.vb

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = beepButtonClicked
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm adding the sound in from my resources

Comment: You can't play sound directly from your resources. It would be better to place the sounds in a folder and play them from axWindowsMediaPlayer using something like "sounds/sound1.wav"

Comment: Ok, how about linking a button to  play a certain sound if a certain picture is displayed? http://pastebin.com/ixtNQsqz doesn't seem to be working.
Edit: I just realised I was missing a parenthesis, but it still doesn't work after fixing that

Comment: Nvm, changed it to check what the button's text says instead of what the picture is and it works.

Comment: With My.Computer.Audio.Play you still have to use a location: My.Computer.Audio.Play("sounds/sound1.wav"). You just can't play sound from the resources.

Comment: @JontyDeeb Does it really work? Glad to hear!

Comment: You can play a .WAV directly from My.Resources as it gets returned as **Stream** and passed to this overload of [Audio.Play()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127796(v=vs.110).aspx).  The persistence of the .WAV in Resources is set to `Embedded in .resx`.